# c# calling function with correct byte array

Tags: c#, arrays, encryption, rijndael

I've got this function I need to call to encrypt my byte array.
The function needs the byte array to be encryptet, a byte array as password and another byte array as initialization vector.
The function itself:

```
public static byte[] Encrypt(byte[] clearData, byte[] Key, byte[] IV) 
{ 

    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(); 


    Rijndael alg = Rijndael.Create(); 


    alg.Key = Key; 
    alg.IV = IV; 


    CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, 
       alg.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write); 


    cs.Write(clearData, 0, clearData.Length); 


    cs.Close(); 


    byte[] encryptedData = ms.ToArray();

    return encryptedData; 
}
```

It may sound strange but I don't get a correct call to use this function. My problem is in using a correct byte array for the password/IV.
I tried using:

```
Encrypt(read, new byte[] { 0x49, 0x49, 0x49, 0x49, 0x4, 0x4, 0x4, 0x4 }, new byte[] { 0x61, 0x61, 0x61, 0x61, 0x61, 0x61, 0x61, 0x61 });
```

I just don't get the trick how to call this function. What's the correct version of a byte array to call this function (password and IV)?

Comment: What do you mean by "don't get a correct call"? What problem are you seeing? What is `read`?

Comment: read stands for my byte array I want to encrypt. The compiler told me all the time, my key had a incorrect size.

Comment: Huh, I didn't know you could represent a byte with a hex value.

Comment: The key must be 128, 192 or 256 bits long (/8 number of bytes), yours is 64 bits. See alg.KeySize for the default. IV must match the BlockSize. You are leaving much undisposed.

Comment: @dehner: I very much doubt that the *compiler* told you that. I suspect that was an exception at execution time. It's important to understand the difference. Now given that you've been told the key has an incorrect length, did you check the key length that *is* valid?

Comment: So using `new byte[] { 0x49, 0x49, 0x49, 0x49, 0x49, 0x49, 0x49, 0x49, 0x49, 0x49, 0x49, 0x49, 0x49, 0x49, 0x49, 0x49 }` should solve key problem right?

Comment: Aside from its weakness the number of key bytes must match alg.KeySize which you can set to one of the 3 values above, ditto for the IV and alg.BlockSize

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can generate your Keys with

```
RijndaelManaged myRijndael = new RijndaelManaged();
myRijndael.GenerateKey();
myRijndael.GenerateIV();
```

then store them somewhere save to use them to encrypt and decrypt your messages

```
byte[] key = myRijindael.Key
byte[] iv = myRijindael.Iv
```

EDIT:
just noticed you are using the Rijindael Class not RijindaelManaged. In the [msdn Example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.security.cryptography.rijndael(v=vs.110).aspx) they say "Create a new instance of the Rijndael class.  This generates a new key and initialization vector (IV)."

So after you created the instance once

```
Rijndael myRijndael = Rijndael.Create()
```

just store the keys.

Comment: To store the Keys you can convert them to a string with Convert.ToBase64String(key) or get the byte array with Convert.FromBase64String(KeyBytes) so you can embed them in the sourcefile (not too safe ;) )